# Unexpected token while parsing Facebook RSS

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms, rss, .net-4.5

I'm trying to parse the facebook RSS but none of them seems to work. Every method I've tried so far result in a different exception. I changed the format to `format=atom10`. I ended up with below code

```
void loadRSS3()
        {
            string url = "https://www.facebook.com/feeds/notifications.php?id=XXXX&viewer=XXXX&key=XXXX&format=atom10";

            var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0)";
            var rep = req.GetResponse();
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.XmlResolver = null;
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;

            var reader = XmlReader.Create(rep.GetResponseStream(), settings);

            SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
        }
```

it give error:

> '= ' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 11,
>   position 171.

How do I make it working?

Comment: Before parsing the feed's content, try to output it as a string to make it is *actually* a feed :)

Comment: Where is this error coming from? Your compiler or the parser? Can you show the content of either your program or the feed around line 11?

Comment: @JulienGenestoux I've tried it and I got same error

Comment: @Roemer It's a run-time (exception) error from `SyndicationFeed.Load()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with same issue, I couldn't solve it using `SyndicationFeed.Load()` but with `XDocument.Parse(xmlString)` instead of.